# Vb6: Selecting a file to later be used via a browse button

Tags: vb6

Here's my code (note that this was given by a friend):

```
Private Sub Browse_Click()
   Dim textfile As String
   textfile = Space(255)
   GetFileNameFromBrowseW Me.hWnd, StrPtr(sSave), 255, StrPtr("c:\"), 
      StrPtr("txt"), StrPtr("Apps (*.txt)" + Chr$(0) + "*.txt" + Chr$(0) +
      "All files (*.*)" + Chr$(0) + "*.*" + Chr$(0)), StrPtr("Select File")
      Text1 = Left$(textfile, lstrlen(textfile))
End Sub
```

Basically later on I edit the text file selected so later I call it just by using textfile in my function.  However I get a path not found so I feel like I'm doing something wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Edit:  All I want to do is select a text file, then later be able to call it and use it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?
Is this code complete? Can I run it by copying it into a VB6 app?

Comment: added a line to the end, this isn't complete it needs some functions declared at the start.

Comment: I'm 99% certain you should use a common dialog OCX. It's just barely possible you're programming in a VBA environment where it isn't available. Just barely. In which case RS Conley's answer is probably what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/GetFileNameFromBrowse.shtml)

I found this code and ran it.

```
Private Const VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT = 2
Private Type OSVERSIONINFO
    dwOSVersionInfoSize As Long
    dwMajorVersion As Long
    dwMinorVersion As Long
    dwBuildNumber As Long
    dwPlatformId As Long
    szCSDVersion As String * 128
End Type
Private Declare Function GetVersionEx Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetVersionExA" (ByRef lpVersionInformation As OSVERSIONINFO) As Long
Private Declare Function GetFileNameFromBrowseW Lib "shell32" Alias "#63" (ByVal hwndOwner As Long, ByVal lpstrFile As Long, ByVal nMaxFile As Long, ByVal lpstrInitialDir As Long, ByVal lpstrDefExt As Long, ByVal lpstrFilter As Long, ByVal lpstrTitle As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetFileNameFromBrowseA Lib "shell32" Alias "#63" (ByVal hwndOwner As Long, ByVal lpstrFile As String, ByVal nMaxFile As Long, ByVal lpstrInitialDir As String, ByVal lpstrDefExt As String, ByVal lpstrFilter As String, ByVal lpstrTitle As String) As Long
Private Sub Form_Load()
    'KPD-Team 2001
    'URL: http://www.allapi.net/
    'E-Mail: KPDTeam@Allapi.net
    Dim sSave As String
    sSave = Space(255)
    'If we're on WinNT, call the unicode version of the function
    If IsWinNT Then
        GetFileNameFromBrowseW Me.hWnd, StrPtr(sSave), 255, StrPtr("c:\"), StrPtr("txt"), StrPtr("Text files (*.txt)" + Chr$(0) + "*.txt" + Chr$(0) + "All files (*.*)" + Chr$(0) + "*.*" + Chr$(0)), StrPtr("The Title")
    'If we're not on WinNT, call the ANSI version of the function
    Else
        GetFileNameFromBrowseA Me.hWnd, sSave, 255, "c:\", "txt", "Text files (*.txt)" + Chr$(0) + "*.txt" + Chr$(0) + "All files (*.*)" + Chr$(0) + "*.*" + Chr$(0), "The Title"
    End If
    'Show the result
    MsgBox sSave
End Sub
Public Function IsWinNT() As Boolean
    Dim myOS As OSVERSIONINFO
    myOS.dwOSVersionInfoSize = Len(myOS)
    GetVersionEx myOS
    IsWinNT = (myOS.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT)
End Function
```

From what I can tell you GetFileName function looks right so my guess the problem is with this

```
Text1 = Left$(textfile, lstrlen(textfile))
```

Use this to check

```
MsgBox "(" & Text1 & ")-(" & textfile & ")"
```

to make sure you are getting the expected result from Left$ and lstrlen

Comment: Might be an idea to suggest using the common dialog at the top of the answer? It would avoid you're answer being downvoted anyway:) It's possible Jackie-Brown is using some VBA environment where you can't use the common dialog, in which case your answer is correct of course.

Comment: A suggestion involving Common dialog OCX is not the minimum thing needed to fix the issue as it introduces a dependency and requires changes to the setup of the program. What I missed is that he is passing sSave instead of textfile. But I showed how to diagnose it and give a known good example.

Answer (score 10):

As shahkalpesh mentioned, you can access this functionality simply using a standard COM library.

In VB6, add the component:

- Project > Components
- On the Controls tab, choose Microsoft Common Dialog Control 6.0 (SP6)

Now on your form, add the new Common Dialog control from the toolbox

In code, you need:

```
CommonDialog.Filter = "Apps (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
CommonDialog.DefaultExt = "txt"
CommonDialog.DialogTitle = "Select File"
CommonDialog.ShowOpen

'The FileName property gives you the variable you need to use
MsgBox CommonDialog.FileName
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this functionality provided by "Common Dialog Controls" in VB6?

My VB6 is a little rusty but basic dialog to choose a file is provided already.
Tools -> Controls -> Microsoft Common Dialog Controls v....

Also, your call to GetFileNameFromBrowseW doesn't include reference the variable - textfile

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sSave contains a pathname, but textfile contains 255 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `sSave` with `textfile`. When you later need to refer to the file picked, use `Text1` (presumably a VB textbox control so Text1 alone is implicitly calling `Text1.Text`, `.Text` being the VB.Textbox's default member).