# How to use open file dialog in VB 6?

Tags: vb6

I want to select a file from the directory or other system. How to use open file dialog in VB 6?

Answer (score 21):

There's some example code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289276/vb6-selecting-a-file-to-later-be-used-via-a-browse-button/289630#289630). Quoting:

In VB6, add the component:

- Project > Components
- On the Controls tab, choose Microsoft Common Dialog Control 6.0 (SP6)

Now on your form, add the new Common Dialog control from the toolbox

In code, you need:

```
CommonDialog1.Filter = "Apps (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
CommonDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"
CommonDialog1.DialogTitle = "Select File"
CommonDialog1.ShowOpen

'The FileName property gives you the variable you need to use
MsgBox CommonDialog1.FileName
```

Answer (score 1):

it needed the "1", but works great thank you

```
CommonDialog1.Filter = "Apps (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
CommonDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"
CommonDialog1.DialogTitle = "Select File"
CommonDialog1.ShowOpen
```

'The FileName property gives you the variable you need to use
    MsgBox CommonDialog1.FileName

Comment: I amended the answer from @Ant

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub main()


  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        .Show
        fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With

    If InStr(fullpath, ".xls") = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open fullpath

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks helpful, but please add text to your answer explaining some context. Especially since this is a late answer compared to the question, it will help to know why your solution is different & better.

Comment: If my understanding is correct this is for VBA and not VB6. Application.FileDialog does not exist in VB6.